Preserve state in NavigationExtras for subsecondary router outlets
I have a classic main outlet and a secondary named outlet.
That secondary outlet has a suboutlet inside.
You can see that structure in Stackblitz here.
So, I have:
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="secondary"></router-outlet>

And, inside secondary:
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

What I want is to pass some info to the suboutlet in secondary. I can pass the info to secondary with NavigationExtras when I do:
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { secondary: 'about' } }], {
  state: { data: 'My data level 1' },
});

But I need that info in the suboutlet inside 'about', not in 'about'. If I do:
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { secondary: 'about/subabout' } }], {
  state: { data: 'My data level 1' },
});

I see my subabout page, but I have no state (state remains in 'about', you can see it in console window).
You can see it working by clicking on ABOUT2 menu.
Any ideas to make this work? I know I can do a service to share the info, but if there exists a solution with state, will be cleaner.

For this problem, we can use the decorator SkipSelf.
This is a dependency injection injector, that skips the instance of the provider on the current component and looks up the DI tree so, it looks at about component's location.
Also I am using LocationStrategy to get the state, this can be used to solve this problem alone, you should not use it for anything else, since it's having a reference to the parent component location and not on the current location due to the decorator.
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-subabout',
  templateUrl: './subabout.component.html',
})
export class SubaboutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    @SkipSelf() private location: LocationStrategy
  ) {
    console.log('sub about', this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state);
    console.log('sub about location', this.location.getState());
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}

Stackblitz Demo

Incredible lesson of knowledge @Naren. It works like a charm, thank you very much. Just a warning: this didn't work if you add skipLocationChange: true to NavigationExtras (I had it in my main project to avoid show full path in browser, but I removed to make it work).
